# Android Performance Tuning for decoding bitmap in SD card

Tags: android, bitmap, decode

My app is downloading image file from internet. To improve performance, I cache the bitmap in memory (both hard and soft cache). I do cache the image file in SD card as well.

Decoding image file from SD card takes noticeable time. I measured this line of code, it takes around `500 - 1800 milliseconds`.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, bitmapOptions);
```

Some facts

- Average  actual image size is 600x600.
- Requested bitmap size is between 200X200 to 400x400
- Have used `bitmapOptions.inSampleSize` to scale the image

Can anyone suggest what is the better way to improve the performance of file decoding?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the image in all formats you need and decode them.

Comment: Hi Roman Black,
I too have same performance while creating bitmap from file on SD card.
can you please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Any task that take time to be performed should to be placed in an AsyncTask. Besides, for image management, I could suggest you to read my previous post and the link in it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041683/smart-image-scaling-down-and-variables-deep-description